# Why is the modified spherical Bessel function an asymptotic solution of this ODE?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, mathematics, differential-equations, asymptotics

I am trying to solve the radial equation with $R = u/r$
$$
\frac{d^2}{dr^2}u - \frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}u + (E-V)u = 0; \qquad V(r) = -\frac{2Z}{\alpha}\frac{e^{-r}}{1 - e^{-r}},
$$
using the shooting method. I have $R(0) = R(\infty) = 0$, but I don't know the value of the derivative at $0$ or asymptotically as $r \to \infty$. To find out what the derivative must be, I have followed Berghe-Fack-Meyer (1989) in their paper on "Numerical methods for solving radial Schrödinger equations". The authors state that in the vicinity of the origin 
$$
V(r) = \frac{V_1}{r} + V_2 + r V_3 + \cdots, \qquad \text{and} \qquad u(r) = r^{l+1}\left( a_1 + a_2r +\cdots \right).
$$
And as $V(r) \to 0$ as $r \to \infty$, the asymptotic behavior at infinity the reduces the ODE to
$$
\frac{d^2}{dr^2}u + Eu(r) = 0.
$$
I understand this, but they claim without explainaition that the asymptotic solution of the ODE is of the form $r j(K r)$ with $K \in \mathbb{R}$ and $j$ the modified spherical Bessel function in both the case that $r \to \infty$ and $r \to 0$. I don't understand why that should be the case. Can you prove it in some detail? Once I understand it, perhaps I can use it to deduce what the derivatives should be at $0$ and at $\infty$.

Comment: What is big $R()$ ? And when you speak of the derivative, which is the function you want to take the derivative of ?

Comment: It is R = u/r  ..